Clearance BGA package to Heatsink's Mounting Holes
In my design I have a BGA-package FGPA (Xilinx Artix-7) on which a custom heatsink must be mounted. The heatsink has to be screwed to the PCB. I am worried about damage to the solder joints of the FPGA due to mechanical stress from mounting the heatsink.
I need a recommendation for the minimum clearance between the heatsink's mounting holes and the FPGA to avoid damage. Since the heatsink will be custom made, I can change the position of the mounting holes.

I need a recommendation for the minimum clearance between the heatsink's mounting holes and the FPGA to avoid damage. I would find extremely difficult to believe that a chip this expensive wouldn't have mechanical and thermal guidelines in their datasheet or application/design notes. I would strongly recommend looking for those documentations :)

The FPGA is an Artix-7 by Xilinx. Unfortunately, the guidelines on heatsinks in their documentation is very generic and only talks about some high-level considerations.

They may have generic designs (and frankly, it would be good follow their designs) but if you're developing a system with a high-volume order for these FPGAs, I'm confident Xilinx/AMD FAEs will support you by recommending the appropriate design for your specific application. That being said, the link you provided is a good guideline for soldering. I didn't read the entire document but I'm sure there's probably something that mentions how much pressure and strain the solder balls underneath can handle. Take a look at Appendix B.

Thanks for the hint, I didn't consider checking the reference design for this issue.
I'll also see if I can get support from Xilinx.

I don't think the mounting holes location is the biggest consideration on protecting an IC from the force of a heatsink.
What needs to be taken into consideration is:

The force of the heatsink on the IC
How you are fastening it to the PCB, and making sure the force is level across the IC and the PCB, tightening down the fasteners can also create displacement and stress in the IC and FR4.

I would also think that placing the holes closer to the IC will create less displacement in the PCB material. If you notice large IC's like the socketed type in motherboards they usually give you a backplate that helps spread the force across the PCB.

Could you explain why placing the holes closer to the IC will create less displacement in the PCB material?

Since the question mentions the interface between a BGA package and a heatsink, a Thermal GAP PAD® Gap Filler between the BGA package and heatsink could help to avoid mechanical stress.
The Selection Guide Thermal Interface Materials shows an example of a GAP PAD between a BGA device and a spring-loaded screw mounted heatsink:



The listed benefits, relevant to the question,  include:


Eliminate air gaps to reduce thermal resistance
Low-stress vibration dampening
Shock absorbing


I haven't used these myself, but found them on a search.
